# Android :loading remote images in application

Tags: android, image, http

I needed to load remote images to my application and bind this image to an QuickcontactBadge object. HttpURLConnection is used to download the image data and BitmapFactory is used to produce the bitmap which will be used as imageview resources.

But I dont know exactly how yo do this?
Can anyone help me over this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you.

```
Bitmap bmImg;
void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
      URL myFileUrl =null;          
      try {
           myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
           HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
           conn.setDoInput(true);
           conn.connect();
           InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

           bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
           imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
      } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

Source : http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Loading_images_from_a_remote_server

See this too

http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/

Comment: I am getting an array of the names of images and i have to concatinate that with the url and then dowload the image.  how to do that

Comment: Following is the array of names of images ["5fryebhq38hqk0jtdrh4kh1nbg4i.jpeg","62v5vgykesnbfttbg2o259kaldjxw1.jpeg","v41aqyen95x7dyr8xg16k8cqq3z7i.jpeg","02mfcai40yqjntzcj8fe0hznjkljvh.jpeg","3jnevkzj4swf6ytgkl30900hz5hkp.jpeg","xtfb35edl3j4d0w6kpej1wpwg0o9y.jpeg","nmjks5vhyhrjcufp3rmpl8xb5k7dhi.jpeg"]

Comment: that is very simple, create a for-loop and call the above function(download image section) with parameter imagesArray[i]. Make sure your images on server are properly indexed.